# Creating Xamarin.Forms .Net Standard app with Azure IOT Library?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm making an iOS/Android app that will work with Azure IoT Hub. The latest Microsoft.Azure.Devices version from what I understand is only compatible with .Net Standard projects. I've been trying to follow these twho tutorials ([1](https://xamarinhelp.com/upgrade-pcl-net-standard-class-library/), [2](https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/)) to convert PCL project to .Net Standard project to no avail, and I'm lost on what I'm doing wrong.

These are the steps that I'm taking.

1. Create new Cross Platform App called **TestProject**. Xamarin.Forms -> Blank App -> Portable Class Library (PCL)
2. Right click solution -> Add New Project -> .Net Standard -> Create .Net Standard Library called **TestProject.Core**
3. Delete the auto generated class Class1.cs and move **App.xaml** and **MainPage.xam**l to **TestProject.Core**.
4. Delete Portable Library **TestProject**.
5. Rename **TestProject.Core** to **TestProject**.
6. Add **TestProject** reference to iOS and Android.
7. Click on **TestProject** and select **Edit TestProject.csproj**. Change PropertyGroup to following:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup> 
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework> 
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-win+net45+wp8+win81+wpa8
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
8. Right click on solution and select Manage Nuget Packages For Solution.
9. Check **Include Prerelease** and install **2.3.5.256-pre6 Xamarin.Forms** on TestProject, TestProject.Droid and TestProject.iOS.
10. Clean and Rebuild solution.
11. Right click on **TestProject** and select Manage Nuget Packages. Install **[Microsft.Azure.Devices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices/1.3.2)**
12. Clean and Rebuild.
13. Add code to **TestProject** that uses Microsoft.Azure.Devices.
14. Rebuild and get error:

    Project File Line Suppression State Error Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
        Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. 
        Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name: 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.dll'

From what I can understand I am missing **Microsoft.Azure.Devices** Nuget package on 
**TestProject.Droid**, however, when I attempt to install it, I get the following error:

```
Could not install package 'System.Threading.Overlapped 4.3.0'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or 
content files that are compatible with that framework.
```

When I try to install *Microsoft.Azure.Devices** on iOS:

```
Could not install package 'System.Threading.Overlapped 4.3.0'. You are trying to install 
this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not 
contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm making an iOS/Android app that will work with Azure IoT Hub. The latest Microsoft.Azure.Devices version from what I understand is only compatible with .Net Standard projects.

Per my understanding, you could leverage the Azure IoT Hub client SDK portable library [Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.PCL) which supports Android, iOS, Windows 10 (UWP) and Windows Phone (WinRT). Also, here is a sample uses `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.PCL`, you could follow [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-xamarin-remote-monitoring-device).

Comment: The PCL does not support the MQTT protocol and will soon be replaced with net standard support: [Reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/30)
The current recommended solution is to create a NetStandard 1.3 class library, add the device client, and reference it in the xamarin android project. [Reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/106) and [Implementation](https://github.com/ryan-z-johnson/AzureIoTXamarin)